# message class by its name

Tags: ros, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have message type name from `rostopic.get_topic_type('/topic')` and I want to subscribe to this topic can I somehow get the class of the message type?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64040/message-class-by-its-name/) by [liborw](https://answers.ros.org/users/2302/liborw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 801 on 2013-05-31

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

from [rostopic code api](http://docs.ros.org/groovy/api/rostopic/html/rostopic-module.html#get_topic_class): `rostopic.get_topic_class('/topic')`

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0